# iPhone UIView not updating instantly

Tags: iphone

My application has a button when clicked it is disabled, an activity indicator displayed and a background task is executed. When this task is completed a callback updates the interface by enabling the button and removing the activity indicator. The problem I having is the task is completing the callback function is executed but for a period of time the activity monitor remains on the screen, the button looks like it is disabled but it is possible to click it again. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you post some codes?

Comment: I'll try and extract some code this is part of a application that we have inherited to some degree.

A quick summary of what it does though. The button action pushes a NSInvocationOperation onto a NSOperationQueue a when the method is executed it stitches some audio files together and the last thing it does is callback to the UIViewController class which sets the enabled property to 'YES' on the button control and calls 'stopAnimating' on the activity indicator.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the callback-method is being executed in a separate thread?
I'm asking, because any calls that have impact on a view should be performed on the main thread.

The problem might be solved by doing the following:

1. create a Method that handles your UI-related code and gets called within your callback method
2. the UI-related code has to be performed on the main thread

It could look a little bit like this:

```
//gets called asynchronously when your operation has completed
-(void)myCallbackHandler {
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:nil 
                                                      waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)updateUI {
    [myActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    [myButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```